# How to get value from slider

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm having problems on the toggle switch and the slider.

The value of the slider is used to increase or decrease the volume of my media element.

However, let's say if I set the value of the slider to '50' and I toggle the switch to 'off' my media element.

How do I capture the previous value from the slider when I toggle the switch back to 'on'?

At the moment, I set the value for slider to '100' when sw_music.IsOn

XAML:

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="154" Margin="45,0,0,0" Height="42" Maximum="100" Value="100"/>
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="sw_music" Header="SOUND" IsOn="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"/>
<MediaElement x:Name="Intro_Sound" Source="SoundEffects/Intro.wav" Volume="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"/>
```

Code-Behind:

```
private void sw_music_Toggle(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(slider.Value >= 1)
    {
        if (sw_music.IsOn)
        {
            slider.Value = 100;
            Intro_Sound.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            slider.Value = 0;
            Intro_Sound.Stop();
        }

        if(slider.Value > 1)
        {
            Intro_Sound.Play();
            sw_music.IsOn = true;
        }
    }
}

private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Intro_Sound.Volume = (slider.Value) / 100;

        if (slider.Value == 0)
        {
            sw_music.IsOn = false;
        }
        else
        {
            sw_music.IsOn = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just don't set the slider value when you toggle music on or off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your `slider.Value` before cut the sound. And restore before play.

Try this:

```
private double savedValue = 100;

private void sw_music_Toggle(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(slider.Value >= 1)
    {
      if (sw_music.IsOn)
      {
        slider.Value = savedValue ;
        Intro_Sound.Play();
      }
      else
      {
        savedValue = slider.Value;
        slider.Value = 0;
        Intro_Sound.Stop();
      }

      if(slider.Value > 1)
      {
        Intro_Sound.Play();
        sw_music.IsOn = true;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @mickro, I've tried it. When I toggle the switch button to on again, it doesnt give me the previous value from the slider which I set.

Comment: oups... my fault if you just copy / paste code above, I did a mistake around `savedValue` and `saveValue`. Should be better right now.

Comment: Hi @mickro, yup i noticed the spelling error but however, it doesnt return my the previous value of the slider when i turn the toggle switch back on..